# javascript code (phonegap app) work in Android 4.3 but not in Android 2.2

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

this javascript work perfect in Android 4.3, but not in Android 2.2, i not understand why (using via phonegap app)

```
var newLi = document.createElement("li");
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = "#"; 
link.innerHTML = (results.rows.item(i).CommonName);
newLi.appendChild(link);
olnew[0].appendChild(newLi);
```

thx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive but I don't think that phonegap supports Android 2.2, maybe this is the problem. When you use Cordova to build your own app (Cordova is what Phonegap is built on top of), it will by default only target Android 2.3.3 and above (API level 10). I'm not sure if you can set the target sdk if you use Phonegap Build, but I bet if you add `android:minSdkVersion="10"` to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file it will work. I'd be interested to know if you can do this using PGB.

Comment: Sorry, 2.3.3, which is API 10, NOT 2.3.2. I edited the post above.